# Replicar código com JS

Tags: javascript

Como eu faço para replicar a div class row-tablet com js?
Eu tenho um array com usuários e sei a quantidade, porém não sei como faz para replicar toda a div e tudo o que tem dentro dela.

```css
.row-table-head, .div-table, .row-table{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .row-table-head{
    display: block;
  }
  .row-table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
  .div-table:hover{
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
  }
  .row-table-head .col-table{
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .row-table .col-table{
   padding: 0px 6px;

  }
```

```html
  <body align="center" onload="setup()">
        <h1>IMPEXPROS</h1>

        <div class="table">
          <div class="row-table-head">
            <div style="background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold" class="col-table">LISTA TODOS USUARIOS</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-table">
            <div class="div-table">
              <a href="" class="col-table">
                  <div>9999</div>
              </a>
              <a href="" class="col-table">
                  <div>vitorpereira</div>
              </a>
              <div class="col-table">
                <input type="button" id="excluirUsuario" value="Excluir">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Acho que pode retirar esse código css da pergunta para não acabar confundindo as pessoas que podem te ajudar uma vez que a pergunta não tem relação com ele. Agora sobre a pergunta você já tentou algo? Poste o código de até onde você chegou até agora.

Comment: Em qual lugar você quer replicá-la? Uma abaixo da outra?

Comment: Victor, eu coloquei o css para a pessoa entende que é tipo uma tabela, eu não tentei nada pois não sei qual função que replica.

Comment: Taffarel, é isso mesmo, vai criar cada linha da tabela de acordo com a quantidade de usuários q tenho no array.

Comment: Você quer replicar a div inteira ou o conteúdo dela?

Comment: Eu vou replicar a div inteira, pq criei uma tabela com divs, os dados vou adicionar enquanto replico a linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra fazer isso com JavaScript, vai ser necessário recriar os elementos.
Vai ficar assim:

```js
class Clientes 
{
    constructor() 
    {
     let teuarray = [{id:'1',nome: 'Humberto'}, {id:'2',nome: 'Doisberto'}];
  const lista = document.getElementById('lista');

     teuarray.map((cliente)=> {
      let divRowT = document.createElement("div");
      divRowT.className = "row-table";
      let divDivT = document.createElement("div");
      divDivT.className = "div-table";

      let id = document.createElement("a");
      id.className = "col-table";
      id.href = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com";     
      let idValue = document.createElement("div");
      idValue.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cliente.id));
      id.appendChild(idValue);
      divDivT.appendChild(id);

      let nome = document.createElement("a");
      nome.className = "col-table";
      nome.href = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com";
      let nomeValue = document.createElement("div");
      nomeValue.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cliente.nome));
      nome.appendChild(nomeValue);
      divDivT.appendChild(nome);

      let divColT = document.createElement("div");
      divColT.className = "col-table";
      let btnExcluir = document.createElement("input");
      btnExcluir.type = "button";
      btnExcluir.id = "excluirUsuario";
      btnExcluir.value = "Excluir"
      divColT.appendChild(btnExcluir);
      divDivT.appendChild(divColT);

      divRowT.appendChild(divDivT);
      lista.appendChild(divRowT);
     });
    }

}

window.onload = event => {
  let clientes = new Clientes();
  clientes.show();
};
```

```css
.row-table-head, .div-table, .row-table{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .row-table-head{
    display: block;
  }
  .row-table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
  .div-table:hover{
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
  }
  .row-table-head .col-table{
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .row-table .col-table{
   padding: 0px 6px;

  }
```

```html
 <body align="center"> <!--retirei o setup(), pois já faço uma chamada no js-->
        <h1>IMPEXPROS</h1>

        <div id="lista" class="table"> <!--inclui um id pra facilitar no js-->
          <div class="row-table-head">
            <div style="background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold" class="col-table">LISTA TODOS USUARIOS</div>
          </div>
<!--           <div class="row-table">
            <div class="div-table">
              <a href="" class="col-table">
                  <div>9999</div>
              </a>
              <a href="" class="col-table">
                  <div>vitorpereira</div>
              </a>
              <div class="col-table">
                <input type="button" id="excluirUsuario" value="Excluir">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
  </body>
```

Tenho um projetinho parecido com Typescript no meu GitHub. Dá uma olhada, pode te ajudar.   [aqui o link](https://github.com/EwertonBello/lista-ts)

Comment: Funciou bem de mais! porem tive que colocar sua função dentro do meu setup, pois eu faço um esquema de promise para pegar uns dados via web, e por classe nao é async.. mas funcionou como esperando! obrigado Ewerton

Comment: Imaginei, como não sabia exatamente o seu objetivo, tentei fazer algo que pudesse ser alterado com mais facilidade. Existem bibliotecas que ajudam nisso, quando não é um projeto grande, eu prefiro fazer sem elas, mas se quiser indico o Handlebars [link](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas eu estou criando essa pagina para um Arduino, tenho muita pouca memória para adicionar bibliotecas, então prefiro fazer tudo no js simples mesmo que o próprio navegador consiga resolver as funções para não sobrecarregar o Arduino. Estou com uma dificuldade de pegar o índex do botão excluir, sabe como consigo pegar?

Comment: Deseja inserir uma função para excluir cada item pelo respectivo botão? Verifica o meu projeto, eu insiro um EventListener em cada botão

Comment: Exato, dei uma olhada, mas manjo muito pouco de DOM, eu coloquei isso dentro da função excluir: "let btnSelecionado = <HTMLSelectElement>event.currentTarget;" e me retorna o seguinte error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Comment: Ah sim hehe é porque tá em typescript, retire essa tag

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99714/discussion-between-ewerton-belo-and-vitor-pereira).

Answer (score 2):

Para duplicar um elemento use o método [`cloneNode();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/element.cloneNode). Esse método possui um argumento booleano onde caso seja `true` a cópia é completa e quando for `false` a cópia é apenas superficial.

Para adicionar o elemento já duplicado use o método [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) que adiciona um nó ao final da lista de filhos de um nó pai especificado.

```js
var tabela = document.getElementById("tabela");  //Elemento em que os clones serão adicionados.
var div = document.getElementById("duplicavel"); //Elemento a ser clonado.

//Por 10 vezes...
for (item in [...Array(10)]) {
  tabela.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true)); //..clona e adiciona.
}
```

```css
.row-table-head,
.div-table,
.row-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row-table-head {
  display: block;
}

.row-table a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.div-table:hover {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.row-table-head .col-table {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row-table .col-table {
  padding: 0px 6px;
}
```

```html
<body align="center" onload="//setup()"><!-- Comentei setup() pois estava dando erro -->
  <h1>IMPEXPROS</h1>

  <div id="tabela" class="table">
    <div class="row-table-head">
      <div style="background-color:black; color:white; font-weight:bold" class="col-table">LISTA TODOS USUARIOS</div>
    </div>
    <div id="duplicavel" class="row-table">
      <div class="div-table">
        <a href="" class="col-table">
          <div>9999</div>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="col-table">
          <div>vitorpereira</div>
        </a>
        <div class="col-table">
          <input type="button" id="excluirUsuario" value="Excluir">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Augusto, obrigado! funcionou como esperado também! e mais simples que o do Ewerton! porém com o dele eu consigo manipular mais coisas.

Comment: @VitorPereira, use o [DOM(Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM) para manipular os valores dos objetos.

Comment: Augusto ainda estou começando no JS, tem coisas como o DOM que não domino, tenho pouca pratica nisso, mas eu irei utilizar a sua resposta em uma outra situação que teve aqui que só preciso replicar umas linhas. Muito grato!